# Copy one 2D array to another 2D array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I used this code to copy one 2D array to another 2D array:

```
Array.Copy(teamPerformance, 0,tempPerformance,0, teamPerformance.Length);
```

However, when I change some data in `tempPerformance` then these changes also apply to `teamPerformance`.
What should I do to control that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is correct: `Array.Copy` performs a *shallow* copy, so the instances of arrays inside the inner dimension get copied by reference. You can use LINQ to make a copy, like this:

```
var copy2d = orig2d.Select(a => a.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/nyAcZV).

Comment: Surely this is only for jagged arrays, as `Select()` is not defined for 2D arrays.

Answer (score 72):

You need Clone()

```
double[,] arr = 
{
   {1, 2},
   {3, 4}
};
double[,] copy = arr.Clone() as double[,];
copy[0, 0] = 2;
//it really copies the values, not a shallow copy, 
//after:
//arr[0,0] will be 1
//copy[0,0] will be 2
```

Comment: I prefer this answer.  Also, I would suggest the assignment to look like this: double[,] copy = (double[,])arr.Clone();

Comment: [Clone()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.clone?view=netframework-4.8) creates a shallow copy by copying the value of each array element onto the new array. For value types, this effectively creates a deep copy, but it will not work for an array of objects or an array of arrays, like in dasblinkenlight's example.

[Demo](http://ideone.com/SAt7Zl)

Comment: While this works, `Array.Copy()` also does the exact same thing when you have a *multidimensional* array of value types like `double` as in the above example. This is rather useful when you have a jagged array (`double[][]` instead of `double[,]`) and when the inner arrays have to be cloned. The OP is most likely referring to a jagged array or a multidimensional array of reference types.

Answer (score 3):

According to MS(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx):

> If sourceArray and destinationArray are both reference-type arrays or are both arrays of type Object, a shallow copy is performed. A shallow copy of an Array is a new Array containing references to the same elements as the original Array. The elements themselves or anything referenced by the elements are not copied. In contrast, a deep copy of an Array copies the elements and everything directly or indirectly referenced by the elements.

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand reading the question, I assume the arrays are filled with reference-types, but C# does not provide a way to "just copy" a reference-type. It will only copy the *reference* to the object (so, then 2 things will point to the same thing).

So, putting reference-types in an array and then making a copy of the array, will not "just" make a copy of a reference-type (because C# can't do that, within an array or not).

That's why 0 of the answers given here will solve the problem. Sheng's answer is correct (but will not solve the problem) -and could maybe use a bit more explaining.

If you want to make copies of references-types, you should look into ways of doing exactly that. Like, converting them to and from JSON, or make a copy-method yourself, maybe by using Reflection.

Comment: Precisely. You can't perform a deep copy unless you tell c# how to perform a deep copy.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
int[] copy = new int[old.Length];
Buffer.BlockCopy(old, 0, copy, 0, old.Length * 4];
```

Note that you have to know the number of bytes you want to copy. Besides that, I am also pretty sure this is very performant.