# Two separate arrays receive same value when changing the value of one of the arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I am working on a Sudoku-Solving project for school and somehow my two arrays are kind of linked together in a way, that when I change a value in `array1` it also changes the value in `array2`.
Please don't hate me because of my code style, I will clean up/improve the code, once I am finished.

I have declared two different string-array variables:
`sudokuFields` and `sudokuUnsolved`.

I am only changing the value of `sudokuFields`, NOT the value of `sudokuUnsolved`, but somehow, when I am debugging the arrays always have the same values..

Any help would be really welcome.

This is my code:

```
class SudokuAlgorithm
{
    public string[,] sudokuFields;
    public string[,] sudokuUnsolved;
    public bool corectRow;
    public bool correctColumn;
    public bool correctField;
    private static int UNASSIGNED = 0;


    public SudokuAlgorithm()
    {
        sudokuFields = new string[9, 9];
    }

    public SudokuAlgorithm(string[,] sudoku, int indexRow, int indexColumn)
    {
        this.sudokuFields = sudoku;
        sudokuUnsolved = sudoku;
        correctRow = TestRow(indexRow, indexColumn);
        correctColumn = TestColumn(indexRow, indexColumn);
        correctField = TestArea(indexRow, indexColumn);
        SolveSudoku();
    }

    private void SolveSudoku()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++) //Column
        {
            for(int j=0;j<9;j++) // Row
            {
                if(SudokuFieldFree(j,i) == true)
                {
                    for(int k=1;k<=9;k++)
                    {
                        sudokuFields[i, j] = k.ToString();
                        if(TestRow(j,i) == false || TestColumn(j,i) == false || TestArea(j,i) == false)
                        {
                            sudokuField[i, j] = "";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (sudokuFields[i, j] == "")
                    {
                        if(j!=0)
                        {
                            for(int l =j-1;l>=0;l--)
                            {
                                if (SudokuAreaFreeUnsolved(l, i) == true)
                                {
                                    j = l-1;
                                    sudokuFields[i, l] = "";
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            i = i - 1;
                            j = 8;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private bool SudokuAreaFree(int indexRow, int indexColumn)
    {
        bool free= false;

        if (sudokuFields[indexColumn, indexRow] == "" || sudokuFields[indexColumn, indexRow] == " " || sudokuFields[indexColumn, indexRow] == null)
        {
            free = true;
            return free;
        }

        return free;
    }


    private bool SudokuAreaFreeUnsolved(int indexRow, int indexColumn)
    {
        bool frei = false;

        if (sudokuUnsolved[indexColumn, indexRow] == "" || sudokuUnsolved[indexColumn, indexRow] == " " || sudokuUnsolved[indexColumn, indexRow] == null)
        {
            free= true;
            return free;
        }

        return free;
    }


    private bool TestRow(int indexRow, int indexColumn)
    {
        bool valid = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            {
                if (sudokuFields[i, indexRow] == sudokuFields[j, indexRow] && sudokuFields[i, indexRow] != " " && i != j)
                {
                    valid = false;
                    return valid;
                }
            }
        }
        return valid;
    }

    private bool TestColumn(int indexRow, int indexColumn)
    {
        bool valid = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            {
                if (sudokuFields[indexColumn, i] == sudokuFields[indexColumn, j] && sudokuFields[indexColumn, i] != " " && i!=j)
                {
                    valid = false;
                    return valid;
                }
            }
        }
        return valid;
    }

    private bool TestArea(int indexRow, int indexColumn)
    {
        bool valid = true;

        if (indexColumn >= 0 && indexColumn <= 2 && indexRow >= 0 && indexRow <= 2)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    if (sudokuFields[indexColumn, indexRow] == sudokuFields[i, j] && sudokuFields[indexColumn, indexRow] != " " && indexColumn != i && indexRow != j)
                    {
                        valid = false;
                        return valid;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (indexColumn >= 3 && indexColumn <= 5 && indexRow >= 0 && indexRow <= 2)
        {
            for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    if (sudokuFields[indexColumn, indexRow] == sudokuFields[i, j] && sudokuFields[indexColumn, indexRow] != " " && indexColumn != i && indexRow != j)
                    {
                        valid = false;
                        return valid;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (indexColumn >= 6 && indexColumn <= 8 && indexRow >= 0 && indexRow <= 2)
        {
            for (int i = 6; i < 9; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    if (sudokuFields[indexColumn, indexRow] == sudokuFields[i, j] && sudokuFields[indexColumn, indexRow] != " " && indexColumn != i && indexRow != j)
                    {
                        valid = false;
                        return valid;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (indexColumn >= 0 && indexColumn <= 2 && indexRow >= 3 && indexRow <= 5)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 3; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    if (sudokuFields[indexColumn, indexRow] == sudokuFields[i, j] && sudokuFields[indexColumn, indexRow] != " " && indexColumn != i && indexRow != j)
                    {
                        valid = false;
                        return valid;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (indexColumn >= 3 && indexColumn <= 5 && indexRow >= 3 && indexRow <= 5)
        {
            for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 3; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    if (sudokuFields[indexColumn, indexRow] == sudokuFields[i, j] && sudokuFields[indexColumn, indexRow] != " " && indexColumn != i && indexRow != j)
                    {
                        valid = false;
                        return valid;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (indexColumn >= 6 && indexColumn <= 8 && indexRow >= 3 && indexRow <= 5)
        {
            for (int i = 6; i < 9; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 3; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    if (sudokuFields[indexColumn, indexRow] == sudokuFields[i, j] && sudokuFields[indexColumn, indexRow] != " " && indexColumn != i && indexRow != j)
                    {
                        valid = false;
                        return valid;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (indexColumn >= 0 && indexColumn <= 2 && indexRow >= 6 && indexRow <= 8)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 6; j < 9; j++)
                {
                    if (sudokuFields[indexColumn, indexRow] == sudokuFields[i, j] && sudokuFields[indexColumn, indexRow] != " " && indexColumn != i && indexRow != j)
                    {
                        valid = false;
                        return valid;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (indexColumn >= 3 && indexColumn <= 5 && indexRow >= 6 && indexRow <= 8)
        {
            for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 6; j < 9; j++)
                {
                    if (sudokuFields[indexColumn, indexRow] == sudokuFields[i, j] && sudokuFields[indexColumn, indexRow] != " " && indexColumn != i && indexRow != j)
                    {
                        valid = false;
                        return valid;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (indexColumn >= 6 && indexColumn <= 8 && indexRow >= 6 && indexRow <= 8)
        {
            for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 6; j < 9; j++)
                {
                    if (sudokuFields[indexColumn, indexRow] == sudokuFields[i, j] && sudokuFields[indexColumn, indexRow] != " " && indexColumn != i && indexRow != j)
                    {
                        valid = false;
                        return valid;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return valid;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should read [mcve]

Comment: You are assigning the constructor array parameter `sudoku` to both variables, so they point to the same array.

Comment: @Jonas, you might get better responses if you follow the suggestions of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when framing your question.  Posting a huge wall of code is a lot for people to sift through.  Creating a MCR can help people help you.

Comment: To expand on what @JanWichelmann said, C# Arrays are reference types, so by assigning `sudoku` to both variables, they both reference that same array.

Comment: Both of these references are assigned to refer to the same location in memory here: `this.sudokuFelder = sudoku; sudokuUngeloest = sudoku;`. Why would they *not* be the same?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725840/copy-one-2d-array-to-another-2d-array)

Comment: I translated the variable/method names. I am sorry if I made a mistake, please correct it in that case.

Answer (score -1):

```
 class Program
{
    public string[] strA;
    public string[] strB;

    public void SetAB(string[] strC)
    {
        this.strA = strC;
        this.strB = strC;
    }

    public void SetA()
    {
        this.strA = new string[2] { "set from SetA()", "set from SetA()" };
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Program p = new Program();

        p.SetAB(new string[2] { "set from SetAB()", "set from SetAB()" });
        Console.WriteLine("strA[0] = " + p.strA[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("strB[0] = " + p.strB[0]);

        Console.WriteLine();

        p.strA[0] = "Test";
        Console.WriteLine("strA[0] = " + p.strA[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("strB[0] = " + p.strB[0]);

        // Why result is such?

        //strA[0] = set from SetAB()
        //strB[0] = set from SetAB()

        //strA[0] = Test
        //strB[0] = Test

        p.SetA();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Now strA and strB are no more attached to same reference object ");
        Console.WriteLine("strA[0] = " + p.strA[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("strB[0] = " + p.strB[0]);

        //strA[0] = set from SetA()
        //strB[0] = Test
    }
```

As they said to you, your problem is these lines of code.

```
this.sudokuFelder = sudoku;
    sudokuUngeloest = sudoku;
```